# MySQL. Сравнить два столбца из двух разных таблиц, но отобразить только отличающиеся

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Необходимо сравнить два столбца из двух разных таблиц, но отобразить только отличающиеся.

```
Таблицы вида products
N   name    stock
1   Иван    200
2   Федор   300
3   Илья    400
4   Анна    500
5   Петр    600
```

и

```
products2
N   name    stock
1   Иван    200
2   Федор   300
3   Илья    000
4   Анна    1000
5   Петр    600
```

Делаю такой запрос

```
SELECT stock FROM products2 WHERE stock IN (SELECT stock FROM products)
```

Выводит совпадающие

```
1   Иван    200
2   Федор   300
5   Петр    600
```

Но мне надо, что бы отобразились отличия

```
3   Илья    000
4   Анна    1000
```

Помогите, не понимаю как сделать….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, что `N` и `name` должны быть равны, и нужно вывести те записи, где `stock` отличается.

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM products t1, products2 t2
WHERE t1.N=t2.N
  AND t1.name=t2.name
  AND t1.stock!=t2.stock
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывод записей из таблицы `products2`, для которых нет либо соответствующих записей в `products` (поле: id) или запись такая есть, но значение поля stock отличается:

```
SELECT p2.* FROM `products2` `p2`
LEFT JOIN `products` AS `p1` ON p2.id=p1.id AND p2.stock=p1.stock
WHERE p1.id IS NULL
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ntZTjhRwvQj8KTTDyFgJX8/0)

Answer (score 0):

Нужно писать (`NOT IN`) а не (`IN`)

```
SELECT stock FROM products2 WHERE stock NOT IN (SELECT stock FROM products)
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ntZTjhRwvQj8KTTDyFgJX8/2)